# How to layout a UILabel and a UIButton and center them?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I want to layout a label next a button, like this:

```
[--[UILabel]-[UIButton]--]
```

I want them to be centered inside its superview, considering that the UILabel and the UIButton have dynamic text length.

How to do that with AutoLayout or UIStackViews?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

How about encapsulating it in a view and center that view to superview?
Something like:

Main view[       centralized view[Label-Button]      ]

[image: Centralize the wrapper view to center of superview.]
[image: Don't give fix width of button or label, just stick them horizontally]

Answer (score 1):

Align both label and button to superview. If you're using storyboard or XIB file, choose the label's `Horizontally Centered Constraint` and in Size Inspector (on the right column of Xcode, 5th item) choose `Label.Trailing` instead of `Label.X`. And give it a value (or zero, whatever you want. This will be the constant between label and center of the view).

After setting them, `Center X Alignment Constraint` for Label in `Size Inspector` should look like this:

[image: UILabel's Center X Alignment Constraint in Size Inspector]

Do the same for the button. But this time, choose `Button.Leading` instead of `Button.X` and give it a constant.
After setting them, `Leading Alignment Constraint` for Button in `Size Inspector` should look like this:
[image: UIButton's Leading Alignment Constraint in Size Inspector]

By this solution, Label and Button will be independent from each other. You can decide their other properties independently.

Your result should look like this:
[image: Autolayout UILabel and UIButton]

Answer (score 1):

Put label and button in StackView and give constraints to that StackView (center horizontaly,center verticaly) to superview

Answer (score -1):

With AutoLayout.  Tweak to your exact situation:

1. Place label and button centered in the view as indicated
2. Lock leading, trailing, and top constraints.  (Don't constrain bottom or height)
3. Constrain label and button as equal widths.
4. Set label to 0 lines.
5. Set button to word wrap.
6. Enjoy.

[image]

Comment: Down voting without a comment does not help anyone learn.  Myself, the OP, or anyone who may read this in the future.  As far as I can tell this answers the question with minimal effort and I show that it works in the simulator.